# Simple php quote syntax error on echo usage inside echo

Tags: php, syntax-error, quotes, submenu

I have no problem with creating php submenu class selected but when i try to create this submenu inside submenu: I can't get it work.

**Problem:** Defining `echo` inside `echo` returning syntax error because of quotes.

```
<ul class="sub_nav">
  <li <?php if ($page=='kurumsal-hakkimizda') {echo "class='selected'";} ?>>
    <a href="<?=BAZ_URL?>/tr/kurumsal-hakkimizda">Hakkımızda</a>
  </li>
  <li <?php if ($page=='kurumsal-ik') {echo "class='selected'";} ?>>
    <a href="<?=BAZ_URL?>/tr/kurumsal-ik">İnsan Kaynakları</a>
    <?php
      if ($page=='kurumsal-ik')
      { echo '
        <ul id="sub_sub_nav">

           <!-- !! PROBLEM STARTS HERE !! -->
           <li class="'if($page=='kurumsal-ik'){echo 'selected'}'">
           <!-- !! CANT USE ECHO INSIDE ECHO BEACUSE OF QUOTES !! -->

            <a href="'.BAZ_URL.'/tr/kurumsal-ik">İnsan Kaynakları Politikamız</a>
           </li>

           <li class="'if($page=='kurumsal-hedef'){echo 'selected'}'">
            <a href="'.BAZ_URL.'/tr/kurumsal-hedef">Kurumsal Hedef</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
     ';}
    ?>
  </li>
  <li <?php if ($page=='kurumsal-haberler') {echo "class='selected'";} ?>>
    <a href="<?=BAZ_URL?>/tr/kurumsal-haberler">Kurumsal Haberler</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have searched this problem's answer like an hour and cound't find the solution, so i've asked here. why **-3** ? Please explain so i can be carefull next time.

Comment: Yeah, I guess nothing wrong from your side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its already inside `echo` right? So do this:

```
<li class="', ($page=='kurumsal-ik') ? 'selected' : '', '">
```

It works for sure. It is called [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)! :)

***Note:** Dot concatenation operator cannot be used here, because, the ternary operator acts as a function returning a value. Only comma* `,` *can be used.*

Comment: And the comma is for ? Maybe you would want to replace it with a dot ?

Comment: No no... Comma only to be put here. `.` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Cosmin `echo` is a language construct to which you can pass multiple parameters, separated by a comma.

Comment: @Cosmin I have clarified your question in the answer itself! :)

Comment: It is working but i have question: `? 'selected' : '',` second `''` after `:` is else right?

Comment: Yes, it is `else` part. It is a simple ternary `if ... else ...`! :)

Comment: @barlasapaydin Yes, a ternary has to do something if the first condition fails.

Comment: Dot concatenation can be used, the ternary operator just needs to be wrapped in brackets, see my post below for an example.

Comment: @JamesKirby Thanks for the info. I have tried to assign many times but it fails. Anyways, point noted. +1 for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the variable and echo it out at the very end:

```
<?php
  if ($page=='kurumsal-ik')
  { 
        $myVar= '
    <ul id="sub_sub_nav">
       <li class="';
    if($page=='kurumsal-ik')
    {
        $myVar .= 'selected';
    }
    $myVar.='">
        <a href="'.BAZ_URL.'/tr/kurumsal-ik">İnsan Kaynakları Politikamız</a>
       </li>

       <li class="';
    if($page=='kurumsal-hedef')
    {
        $myVar.= 'selected';
    }
    $myVar.='">
        <a href="'.BAZ_URL.'/tr/kurumsal-hedef">Kurumsal Hedef</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
    ';
    echo $myVar;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Praveen has said, it's already within an echo so there is no need to use another.
I believe the syntax for a [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) within an echo is:

```
<?php echo '<li class="' . ( $page == 'page_name' ? 'selected' : '' ) . '"><a href="/">Link</a></li>'; ?>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

One the useful features of PHP is that it directly outputs everything that is outside the `<?php` and `?>` tags, so you don't need long echo statements.

This is particularly practical when used in combination with the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Your code would be much more readable like this:

```
<?php if($page=='kurumsal-ik'): ?>
    <ul id="sub_sub_nav">

    <li class="<?php if($page=='kurumsal-ik') echo 'selected';?>">
        <a href="<?php echo BAZ_URL; ?>/tr/kurumsal-ik">İnsan Kaynakları Politikamız</a>
    </li>

    <li class="<?php if($page=='kurumsal-hedef') echo 'selected';?>">
        <a href="<?php echo BAZ_URL; ?>/tr/kurumsal-hedef">Kurumsal Hedef</a>
    </li>

    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

P. S.
You can shorten your code by using the shorthand `<?=`, which means `<?php echo`.